# Sharepoint 2010 populate dropdown list with site users

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a small problem that I need to deal with. I have to create a form in SharePoint Designer 2010 with two fields: User name and Group. These are dropdown lists from which the user can select user and group and save the user's ID and the group's ID in a SQL table. The problem is I do not know how to populate the list with the information needed: Users names, based on their IDs and Site groups, based on their IDs, all from the current site. Do you have ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not something you can achieve through SharePoint Designer. SharePoint Designer is made with Power Users in mind. What you are looking for is more of a developer task. As such, you would need to use Visual Studio.